# Efficiently executing complex Python code in R

Tags: python, r

I'm looking for an efficient way to execute Python code in a fast and flexible way in R.

The problem is that I want to execute a particular method from topological data analysis, called *persistent homology*, which you don't really need to know in detail to understand the problem I'm dealing with.

The thing is that computing persistent homology is not the most easiest thing to do when working with large data sets, as it requires both a lot of memory and computational time.

Executing the method implemented in the R-package *TDA* is however very inconvenient: it crashes starting at around 800 data points and doesn't really allow me to use approximation algorithms.

In contrast, the Python package *Ripser* allows me to do the computation on a few thousands of points with ease in Python. Furthermore, it also allows one to provide a parameter that approximates the result for even larger data sets, and can also store the output I want. In summary, it is much more convenient to compute persistent homology with this package.

However, since everything else I'm working on is in R, it would also be lot more convenient for me to execute the code from the Ripser package in R as well. An illustrative example of this is as follows:

```
# Import R libraries

library("reticulate") # Conduct Python code in R
library("ggplot2") # plotting

# Import Python packages

ripser <- import("ripser") # Python package for computing persistent homology
persim <- import("persim") # Python package for many tools used in analyzing Persistence Diagrams

# Generate data on circle

set.seed(42)

npoints <- 200
theta <- 2 * pi * runif(npoints)
noise <- cbind(rnorm(npoints, sd=0.1), rnorm(npoints, sd=0.1))
X <- data.frame(x=cos(theta) + noise[,1], y=sin(theta) + noise[,2])

# Compute persistent homology on full data

PHfull <- ripser$ripser(X, do_cocycles=TRUE) # slow if X is large

# Plot diagrams

persim$plot_diagrams(PHfull$dgms) # crashes
```

Now I have two problems when using this code:

- The persistent homology computation performed by the ripser function works perfectly fine in this example. However, when I increase the number of data points in X, say npoints ~ 2000, the computation will take ages compared to around 30 seconds when I would perform the computation straightforwardly in Python. I don't really know what's happening behind the scenes that causes this huge difference in computational times. Is this because R is perhaps less convenient than Python for this example, and in stead of converting my arguments to the custom types in Python and executing the code in Python, the Python code is converted to R code? I am looking for an approach that combines this flexibility and efficient type conversion with the speed of Python.
- In Python, the analog to the last line would plot an image based on the result of my persistent homology computation. However, executing this line causes R to crash. Is there a possible way to show the image that would normally result in Python in R?

Comment: I don't use R but I see lots of raving about `ggplot`. How big is the actual data output from Python? One approach, though clunky, would be to call the Python code as a subprocess and get it to dump the data to disk, then read it back into R. I don't even know where to begin in understanding why R can't execute the python code at native speed sorry

Comment: It seems a bit of a pickle to determine as the output in Python is a nested dictionary containing different type of objects such as arrays and others. However, if I summed everything correctly, the output on a data set of 2000 points would be of about 32Mb in Python.

Comment: That wouldn't be a huge burden for I/O but it also perhaps hints at the speed difference; I wonder whether there is some inefficient overhead in converting the mixed output from python to R. If you have mixed types, I guess they will all have to be converted